# Test if props are passed (Without using Enzyme)

Tags: reactjs

I want to test if my props are passed, but without using Enzyme,

I tried to find documentation on the internet, but all the tutorials are with Enzyme.

```
describe('App Component', () => {
  it('renders the Counter wrapper', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<App />);
    expect(wrapper.find(Counter)).to.have.length(1);
  });

  it('passes all props to Counter wrapper', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<App />);
    let counterWrapper = wrapper.find(Counter);

    expect(counterWrapper.props().counter).to.equal(0);

    wrapper.setState({ counter: -1 });

    counterWrapper = wrapper.find(Counter);
    expect(counterWrapper.props().counter).to.equal(-1);
  });
```

Could someone help me? Can I do this with jest? Or I do need a third-party library like 'react-testing-library'?

Comment: What's your motivation to not use Enzyme? Because it's up to the job.

Comment: shallow is already from Enzyme, import { shallow } from 'enzyme'; why you use Enzyme yet also mention No Enzyme?

Comment: I can't use Enzyme cuz my company does not want to, and I don't find any good documentation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enzyme `shallow` is primarily intended for *isolated unit tests* like the one that was listed, only the implementation of tested unit is asserted. It offers some instrumentation (and also non-compliant behaviour) that doesn't exist in React itself.

react-testing-library is primarily intended for *blackbox functional tests*, the effects of units on resulting DOM are asserted.

React's own ReactTestUtils also offer some basic functionality, a subset of Enzyme and react-testing-library features, including [shallow renderer](https://reactjs.org/docs/shallow-renderer.html) for isolated tests.

It's possible to do isolated tests and assert the implementation without Enzyme, this results in boilerplate code. The approach isn't specific to testing library, it could be achieved with any renderer, including React's test renderer's [snapshot testing](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/snapshot-testing). Everything (`Counter` component) but tested unit (`App` component) should be mocked with Jest, e.g.:

```
  it('passes all props to Counter wrapper', async () => {
    const CounterMock = jest.fn(() => 'Counter');
    jest.mock('./counter-module', () => CounterMock);
    const App = await import('./app-module');

    // render <App/> and assert that the result is <div>Counter</div> 

    expect(CounterMock).toBeCalledWith({ counter: 0 });
  });
```